# Is this request for work question off topic, too broad, or unclear?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

https://stackoverflow.com/q/18551215/1026459

It is basically requesting that someone come along and implement a feature which is described in the question. The feature will detect user input live and then manipulate a label. Upon a condition being met, the feature will submit the page.

There is absolutely no code, and the actual question at the bottom of the body is "Any idea how I can do that?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, I believe that these types of questions waste the most time of regular users.

It is a request for someone else to do the work of the OP by implementing a full feature.

I am not sure which close reason is "perfect", but from [the discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185142/178816) when the new rules were posted, it seems to me that this is lacking of "minimal understanding" and should be closed as off topic.